# How can I add a Popup window for each of my dynamically created "search result BLOCKS"

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic, popup

I need to show up a popup window  when I click the "view" button on every search result blocks. I tried with different java-script codings but button/popup didn't work. In below code I have only added the button ("output += "button id="show">VIEW</button'") and can someone tell me how I can add a popup window to that "view" button ? (a popup similar to this https://codepen.io/joshuaward/pen/jYZXGo (but no need css decorations))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <title>INVOICE search</title>
  
  <style>
  .poo{min-height:20px;padding:20px;background-color:#f5f5f5;border:10px solid white;border-radius:30px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);box-shadow:inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05)}
  

  
  </style>
  
  
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" style="padding:50px 250px;">
    <h1>Live Search</h1>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="input" class="form-control input-lg" id="txt-search" placeholder="Type your search character">
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="filter-records" style=""></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
  
  




  
  
  
  


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#header').load('../header-ads.html');
$('#footer').load('../footer-ads.html');

    var data = [{"DATE":"2019-05-27T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":2,"NAME":"3Com Corp","VEHICLE NO":"32425","ITEM1":"DAT","NO OF PACKS1":"432","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"5","UNIT PRICE1":"45","REJECTIONS1":"6","ITEM2":"FAJ","NO OF PACKS2":"65","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"56","UNIT PRICE2":"56","REJECTIONS2":"56646","ITEM3":"FAP","NO OF PACKS3":"78","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"786","UNIT PRICE3":"85","REJECTIONS3":"676","ITEM4":"7","NO OF PACKS4":"676","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"4634643","UNIT PRICE4":"46436","REJECTIONS4":"6436","ITEM5":"656","NO OF PACKS5":"3466","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"646","UNIT PRICE5":"46436","REJECTIONS5":"46436","Reciever Name":"FDGDGH","Reciever Id no ":"56","REMARKS":"FGGH","PREPARED BY":"GFH","INVOICE NO":"HG656","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":"545"},{"DATE":"2019-05-28T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":3,"NAME":"3M Company","VEHICLE NO":"32426","ITEM1":"DAR","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"FAP","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"DAT","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""},{"DATE":"2019-05-29T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":4,"NAME":"A.G. Edwards Inc.","VEHICLE NO":"","ITEM1":"JAR","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"JAR","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"FAJ","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""},{"DATE":"2019-05-30T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":5,"NAME":"Abbott Laboratories","VEHICLE NO":"","ITEM1":"FAP","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"DAT","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"DAR","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""},{"DATE":"2019-05-31T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":6,"NAME":"Abercrombie & Fitch Co.","VEHICLE NO":"","ITEM1":"FAJ","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"DAR","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"JAR","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""},{"DATE":"2019-06-01T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":7,"NAME":"ABM Industries Incorporated","VEHICLE NO":"","ITEM1":"DAT","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"FAJ","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"FAP","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""},{"DATE":"2019-06-02T18:30:00.000Z","DESPATCH NO":8,"NAME":"Ace Hardware Corporation","VEHICLE NO":"","ITEM1":"DAR","NO OF PACKS1":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK1":"","UNIT PRICE1":"","REJECTIONS1":"","ITEM2":"FAP","NO OF PACKS2":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK2":"","UNIT PRICE2":"","REJECTIONS2":"","ITEM3":"DAT","NO OF PACKS3":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK3":"","UNIT PRICE3":"","REJECTIONS3":"","ITEM4":"","NO OF PACKS4":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK4":"","UNIT PRICE4":"","REJECTIONS4":"","ITEM5":"","NO OF PACKS5":"","IMASS / IQTY OF A PACK5":"","UNIT PRICE5":"","REJECTIONS5":"","Reciever Name":"","Reciever Id no ":"","REMARKS":"","PREPARED BY":"","INVOICE NO":"","INVOICE SUBMITTED DATE":""}]

$('#txt-search').keyup(function(){
            var searchField = $(this).val();
            if(searchField === '')  {
                $('#filter-records').html('');
                return;
            }
            
            var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
            var output = '<div class="row">';
            var count = 1;
              $.each(data, function(key, val){
                if ((val.DATE.search(regex) != -1) || (val.NAME.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ITEM1.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ITEM2.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ITEM3.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ITEM4.search(regex) != -1) || (val.ITEM5.search(regex) != -1)) {
                  output += '<div class="col-md-6  poo">';
                  output += '<div class="col-md-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="https://catnop.com/a.png" alt="'+ val.NAME +'" /></div>';
                  output += '<div class="col-md-7">';
                  output += '<h5>' + val.NAME + '</h5>';
                  output += '<p>' + val.DATE + '</p>'
                  output += '<p>' + val.ITEM1 +  '&nbsp'
                  output += ',' + val.ITEM2 +  '&nbsp'
                  output += ',' + val.ITEM3 +  '&nbsp'
                  output += ',' + val.ITEM4 +  '&nbsp'
                  output += ',' + val.ITEM5 +  '</p>'
                  
                  output += '<button id="show">VIEW</button>'
                  output += '</div>';
                  output += '</div>';
                  
                  
                  if(count%2 == 0){
                    output += '</div><div class="row">'
                  }
                  count++;
                }
              });
              output += '</div>';
              
              $('#filter-records').html(output);
        });
  });
  

</script>
```